# What is the Difference between SQL Server 2008R2 and SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

I want to take my project from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014. But I want to learn what is T-SQL the difference between 2008 R2 and 2014 for Database Engine? I mean is there any end of life syntax for SQL Server 2014? 
Like from 2008 to 2012 usage of FAST is disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend reading through the [Backward Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143532%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) sections on BOL as they tend to list all the Deprecated and Discontinued features of each version of SQL Server.

Also, when you're coming to upgrade, run the [Upgrade Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144256%28v=sql.120%29.aspx). This will give you details of any issues that you will need to fix before upgrading to 2014